# Can writing into reserved space of std::vector result in a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I hope this is not a too controversial question, but I cannot find a proper full answer on SO. This is also not a question about the difference between the methods `reserve` and `resize` or the difference between `capacity` and `size`, which are (hopefully) clear to me and have often enough been asked on SO. Also, this is not a question, if this is good practice at all, which it is not!

Consider the following situation:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
  double a, b;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::vector<Foo> Vec;
  Vec.reserve(100);

  Foo foo;
  foo.a = -13.131;
  foo.b = 3.141;

  for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    Vec[i] = foo;

  for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    std::cout << Vec[i].a << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I first create a `std::vector` of Foo and the reserve memory, but don't resize the vector. Clearly `size() = 0`, BUT the memory for 100 elements has been allocated and may now be freely used by my program, so technically, writing to and reading from any position in memory of these elements cannot result in a segmentation fault, is that correct?

I have tried to run this code on Ubuntu 14.04 and everything works as expected, all 100 elements have been written to successfully and all outputs are also -13.131, even though the vector size remains at 0. If I look for through many answers on SO, they all correctly point out that it results in undefined behaviour, because the elements are not initialized, but could it actually result in a segmentation fault in any way (not talking about accessing elements of unitialized pointers in a vector etc.)?

A question similar to this has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348026/stdvector-segmentation-fault-with-and-without-initialization) and that seems to confirm my thought, but would it in principle work accross all platforms that support compilation of C++?

Comment: undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: Going out of bounds is undefined behavior. End of story really.

Comment: It can result in a segmentation fault, or it might exploit an elevated permission weakness of your shell and format your hard drive, or it might get up at night and put a tortoise under your blanket. Thus are the delights of UB. You cannot rely on something happening or not happening.

Comment: A compiler could still foreseeably recognize this UB and optimize around that. Say this is in an `if (ptr == nullptr)` block. Then a reasonable optimization would be to assume `ptr` is never null, which can lead to more regular segfaults. In short, you can't rely on UB continuing to work.

Answer (score 4):

Once you have undefined behaviour, it is well, undefined behaviour.
One of the key aspects of undefined behaviour is that you can't be sure what the behaviour would be on different system and compiler. Now you could look at the code of a specific compiler and a specific library implementation and you will see it acts as you expect it to.

But I don't think you will find anyone who is willing to bet that this will work across all different systems, compilers and library implementations.

Just for instance, what if a specific vector implementation decide to use the reserved memory for internal information? Maybe it is unlikely, but how can you be sure no system is actually doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider a concrete example - the std::vector implementation that when reserve() is called, it allocates the memory, but then starts performing the copy on a background thread - because it can...  *shrugs* who knows what will happen in the near future!  So while it's copying, all reads are unlocked and go straight to the old memory area because that's still good for reading.

Now attempting to read something out of range will be attempting to read random memory, and not what you're asserting should be your new allocated memory.

So as the comments and the other answer says, undefined is undefined.